# hibernate how to map collection based on some criteria

Tags: hibernate, mapping

I'm trying to only match a set partially, I mean for example
in my Product.hbm.xml, I have a  of "recentOrders" which means I only want the very latest orders (order by timestamp of "Order")

```
    <set cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" name="recentOrders" lazy="true"   >        
        <key on-delete="cascade">
            <column name="product_id" not-null="true"/>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.xx.Order"/>
    </set>
```

should I　ｕｓｅ　ａｔｔｒｉｂｕｔｅ　ｏｆ　"subselect" or "where" ? if yes, how ?

btw,I'm using hibernate 3.x, hibernate will not add any sql clause which is specified by attribute of "subselect" or "where"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [good explanation](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t43955.html). You can do it inside HQL query itself if it's just a single time need. There is another option - using filters, note though that they are set for the session, not for a particular query.

Comment: thanks ctapobep. It would be great if there's a way to map this "recentOrders" as a property of my Product class for my other purpose.

Comment: Didn't get your question, does it relate to the one described in the original post?

Comment: please forgive my english. What I want to say is I need to map this <set> as a property of Product class, thus I can reuse this property for my other codes.

Comment: I googled a lot, seems there's no way to do it. So I have to use what you have recommended, or use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589299/write-hql-clause-using-hibernate-criteria-api